# get all nodes that is connected through their links

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes

Does anybody already know how to get all the nodes that is connected through their links.

Here is my current code that works only in one level:

```
 var connectedLinks = [];
.on('mouseover', function(d) {   
  link.style('stroke-width', function(l) {
        if (d === l.source || d === l.target) {
          connectedLinks.push({type: 'direct', s: l.source.index, t: l.target.index});
        return 5;
      } else {
         connectedLinks.push({type: 'indirect', s: l.source.index, t: l.target.index});
        return 4;
      }
  });
```

My jsfiddle [Nodes Highlighting](https://jsfiddle.net/dondellbatac/awuos8po/4/)

My function to iterate through links

```
function checkIfLinkIsInPipeline(){
 for(var i in connectedLinks){
   if(connectedLinks[i]['type'] == "indirect") {
     console.log("a " + JSON.stringify(connectedLinks[i]));  
     digNeighbor(connectedLinks[i]['s'], connectedLinks[i]['t']);        
   }
 }
}

  function digNeighbor(s, t) {
    for(var j in connectedLinks) {
      if(connectedLinks[j]['type'] == "direct"){
        console.log("b " + JSON.stringify(connectedLinks[j]));  
      }

if(connectedLinks[j]['type'] == "direct" &&
   (connectedLinks[j]['s'] == s ||
    connectedLinks[j]['s'] == t ||
    connectedLinks[j]['t'] == s ||
    connectedLinks[j]['t'] == t)) {
    connectedLinks.push({type: "direct", s: s, t: t});
    console.log("changed to direct " + JSON.stringify({type: "direct", s: s, t: t}));
  }
}
}
```

Comment: my intuition says that you need make that function a named function and then recursively go down the links. Are you able to supply a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi @derp. I just added snippet of the function I am using and also added the jsfiddle. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i got an inefficient sample to work in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hreqe9yo/2/). You should be able to apply it to your fiddle.

The important code is here:

```
.on('mouseover', function fillBlue(datum, index) {
    console.log('firing for ', this);
    d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");
    links.forEach(function(link) {
      if (link.source.index === index) {
        svg.selectAll('.node').each(function(d, i) {
          if (i === link.target.index) {
            fillBlue.call(this, d, i);
          }
        })
      }
    })
  })
```

Lets go through it step by step.

1. We apply the fill style for our current node.
2. We then find the links that start from our current node.
3. We then find all the nodes that end from those links
4. We call this function for those nodes.